This connection is missing required metadata for the "Add your data" feature in the chat playground
I am having the same issue. I have data inside the cosmos db database. I added the data to Azure Search AI. I looked at the index and indexer and both are fine. I can see the data there. However, when I try to add the data to my AI studio, I get the following error "This connection is missing required metadata for the "Add your data" feature in the chat playground. Ensure your Search resource exists and you have read access to it in the Azure Portal." It says to click to fix but you click on that and nothing happens. Any help

Are you having at least one string type field in you index?
